# 3 Days old Macbook Pro 16" CPU Temperature reaching 97C°

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, temperature

This is my first macbook ever. After 3 Days of using this 16" Macbook Pro, the temperature of the CPU core reaches 97°C.

it happens when i am using Android studio with the simulator to test an 8 megabyte app (a webview).

it also heats when i am using chrome but doesn't reach 97°C, nevertheless i can boil an egg over it.

Should i return it and ask for another? if i return it and get the same would i have the same issue? is this common in macbooks?

here is the detail of the recorded temperatures
[image]

Comment: Wow, those are hot temperatures. And can’t believe you can boil an egg on the thing!

Comment: it's just a figure of speech, but yes it is doable

Comment: Why is this an issue? Those temps are normal for a MacBook under load. Your battery temperature looks good.  Check CPU load with Activity Monitor.  Over 100 for CPU would be a worry.